# How to convert time string to epoch time timestamp

Tags: python

I am converting an OHLC dataframe for data manipulation and I am required that the datetime column is in epoch time format. At present is as follows:

2020-11-18 14:30:00-05:00

The data type returned on the column is 'object' and the last 6 digits i undertend represent the 'US/Eastern' timezone.

How to convert the whole column to Epoch Time timestamp correctly? Tnx

Comment: Please add a data example, then it is easier to help. You might need to convert your date column to a proper format, and then use the epoch time function on the datetime object afterwards https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 0):

you can use dateparser to get the data in epoch form:

```
import dateparser
dateparser.parse("2020-11-18 14:30:00-05:00").timestamp()
```